# Finding a Updated Collection in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

In a previous question, I was told to use `update()` and `upsert: true` instead of `insert()` in a MongoDB to prevent duplicates. Cool, I liked the idea and I implemented it. My issue is that when I try to find the document inside the collection, I get a `No Document Found` Error. So I am a little confused on why it is not finding it even though I told it to insert.

Code examples:

```js
function insertCompanies(companyID, companyURL, companyAppID) {
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
  } else {
   console.log("We are connected");
  }
  
  var collection = db.collection('Companies');
  var company = {
   "companyProfileID": companyID,
   "url": companyURL,
   "appID": companyAppID
  };
  collection.update(
  {
   "company.companyProfileID": company.companyProfileID
  }, {
   company
  }, {
   upsert: true
  }, function(err, result) {
   if (err) {
    //console.log(err);
   } else {
    console.log(result);
   }
  });
  db.close();
 });
}

function getCompany(companyUrl, app, callback) {
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
  } else {
   console.log("We are connected");
  }
  
  var collection = db.collection('Companies');
  collection.find({url: companyUrl.toLowerCase(), appID: app}).toArray(function (err, result) {
   if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    callback(err);
   } else if (result.length) {
    console.log(result);
    callback(result);
   } else {
    console.log("No document found");
    callback(err);
   }
  });
  db.close();
 });
}
```

I am inserting a company into a collection of companies using the `insertCompanies(companyID, companyURL, companyAppID)` function. Here is a sample function call: `insertCompanies("86660a5b-7f61-4238-889d-1cc3087947b9", "sentsoftware.com", 1);`

But when I call `getCompanies`, I get a `No Document Found`. Am I using `update()` incorrectly?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Have you had a look at what data, if any, is being inserted into the database? Without doing that, you might have a problem with either the *insertCompanies* function or the *getCompany* function, without knowing which.